# code igniter php - how to echo model data within the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new at code igniter and I'm trying to figure out how to utilize data returned from my database. I have a simple query in the model:

```
function feed_get_all_trees(){
        $query = $this->db->get('trees');
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Then in the controller, I am building an XML Feed with the help of an XML plugin library I found, so I want to echo the data out in the controller rather than in a view. Normally, if I was using a view, I'd do this:

```
$this->load->model('Model_form','', TRUE);
        $data['rows'] = $this->Model_form->feed_get_all_trees(); //gets the available groups for the dropdown
        $this->load->view('view_name',$data);
        }
```

But in order to construct my XML feed - I need to access data right here. If I try this:

```
foreach ($rows as $r){
            $treeName = $r->tree_name;
            $xml->startBranch('tree');
                $xml->addNode('treeName',$treeName);
            $xml->endBranch();
```

I get an error, because it doesn't know what `$rows` is. How do I refer to `data['rows']` here so I can access the data?

Comment: `foreach ($data['rows'] as $r){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand what you're trying to do as I've never used any XML plugin, but wouldn't you just do something like this to access the data?

```
$data['rows'] = $this->Model_form->feed_get_all_trees(); 
foreach($data['rows'] as $row) { ... }
```